# Bash: How to feed a command with the multiple results generated by one subcommand

Tags: bash, gcc

I want to process each source code file after it has been preprocessed:

```
myprocess `gcc -E file1.c`  
myprocess `gcc -E file2.c`  
...  
myprocess `gcc -E fileN.c`
```

This gets tedious so how do I make this a single command?
That is, something along the line:

```
myprocess SOMETHINGMAGIC(gcc -E file*.c)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like

```
   for i in file*.c ; do
        myprocess `gcc -E $i`
    done
```

Comment: I think you mean "for" not "foreach" for bash.

Comment: yep, it should be:  
for i in file*.c; do

Comment: Right.  Fixed now, thanks guys.  No excuses - I normally hate C-shell.

Comment: ok, this will work. i was thinking about a more powerful form of $(), thus didn't think of an explicit loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is part of an ongoing processes (as opposed to a one time thing), use `make`, it is good at automating work pipelines.

In particular use suffix rules with traditional make or gmake style implicit rules.

Here is an outline for a suffix rule implementation:

```
.c.cpre:
         $(CC) -E $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
.cpre.cmy:
         $(MY_PROCESS) $<
         # Or whatever syntax you support..
         #
         # You could 
         # $(RM) $<
         # here, but I don't recommend it
.cmy.o:
         $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
         # $(RM) $<
```

Comment: An interesting solution, and not one I would have thought of.  Probably not worth it unless he's going to have to do this many times during the life of his project.

Comment: @Paul: True, enough. But everytime, I think "this is a one off so why automate it?" I have to do it again next week. Grrr...

Comment: I didn't think of this at all! Thanks, this will do!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?:

```
for i in file*.c ; do 
    echo "Header for myprocess: $i" 
    gcc -E $i 2>&1 
done | myprocess
```

`2>&1` assumes you want to grab stderr, too
`echo ...` gives myprocess a starting point for each compilation

Answer (score 1):

No magic nedded, just

```
my_process $(gcc -E *.c)
```

Note that I used the $(command) form because backticks are deprecated.

As an aside: are you sure you want to do *that*? You are putting the whole output of gcc -E as command line parameters of my_process. Not sure this is what you want. Maybe you want to use a simple pipe

```
gcc -E file.c | my_process
```

so that the output of gcc becomes the input of my_process.

In the latter case something like

```
for c_file in *.c ; do
    gcc -E $c_file | myprocess > ${c_file}.processed
done
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
myprocess {$(gcc -E file1.c),$(gcc -E file2.c),$(gcc -E file3.c)}
```

Or if you pipe it:

```
{$(gcc -E file1.c),$(gcc -E file2.c),$(gcc -E file3.c)} | myprocess
```

It's been a while since I've used bash, so, please, point out my mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

ls file*.c | xargs --replace myprocess $(gcc -E {})